# How to use conditional ternary operator for jsx react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to return null or jsx based on the isOpen value.

Below is my code,

```
function Child ()  {
    const isOpen = true;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <wrapper>
                <div> title</div>
                <button> click me </button>
            </wrapper>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

How can i use ternary operator to return null or the above jsx based on isOpen value. if its true it should return jsx if not null.

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Have you had a specific problem using it? Give a [mre], at the moment there's no visible attempt to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a ternary:

```
function Child ()  {
    const isOpen = <whatever-condition>;
    return (
        isOpen ?
        <Fragment>
            <wrapper>
                <div> title</div>
                <button> click me </button>
            </wrapper>
        </Fragment>
        : null
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need ternary operator to do this.

1. Just return null if `isOpen == false`:

```
function Child ()  {
    const isOpen = true;

    if (!isOpen) return null;

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <wrapper>
                <div> title</div>
                <button> click me </button>
            </wrapper>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

2. Use `&&` operator:

```
function Child ()  {
    const isOpen = true;
    return isOpen && (
        <Fragment>
            <wrapper>
                <div> title</div>
                <button> click me </button>
            </wrapper>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```